# Handling orientation from sensors and by triggering it manually

Tags: android, orientation

I have a layout that I am currently supporting orientation change by overwriting `onConfigurationChanged` and arranging views based on the selected orientation. Trying to support that same functionality by triggering it from a minimize/expand view button, but the orientation change getting called twice with the new and old orientations.

I have `adjustConfig(int orientation)` method that takes care about moving the views, hiding/showing what needed - it does the job.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    adjustConfig(newConfig.orientation);
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

  //since fullScreeBtn blocks the orientation sensors, we enable it back 
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
    }
}

public void adjustConfig (int orientation) {
// do some hide/show work based on the orientation type
}
```

`fullScreeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setRequestedOrientation(
                   getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 
                   Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? 
                   ActivityInfo.CREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT :
                        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }
        });`

I have a full-screen/minimize button that calls to 
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)` or 
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.CREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)` based on the orientation I want to change and that triggers in turn `onConfigurationChanged` which handles my configuration, so far all good, but the problem is that for example, if I am on a portrait and clicking on the button to switch to landscape, the flow works and kicks off `onConfigurationChanged` with new landscape configuration which makes the change, but then immediately `onConfigurationChanged` gets called again with the current mode which is portrait and I end up with the initial state - portrait again.

EDIT: Currently the way the code works is you can either start with rotating physically the phone and switching back and forth between portrait and landscape either taping on the minimize/full screen, but not both, since the moment I call 
`setRequestedOrientation` in the `fullScreeBtn` it forces the orientation and disables the sensor listening, so when I tap on full screen it rotates the screen as I want, then I would rotate the phone to see it, but from this point I am stuck as I can't rotate back physically, only by clicking on the minimize image again.

My goal is to have a support in both the sensors and the manual option, so if I click on `fullScreeBtn` it would switch to landscape mode and the user would need to rotate his phone to adjust a comfortable view ,exactly like YouTube does today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say:

> 1. the problem is that for example, if I am on a portrait and clicking on
>      the button to switch to landscape, the flow works and kicks off
>      onConfigurationChanged with new landscape configuration which makes
>      the change
> 2. but then immediately onConfigurationChanged gets called again with the
>      current mode which is portrait and I end up with the initial state -
>      portrait again.

I tried to replicate your case, but unless some details are missing, I can't see why point nr. 2 would happen. So after clicking on the button to switch to landscape the app stays like that in landscape - which is also what I was expecting.

Just to make sure no important details are left:

- Are you listening by any chance to the `OrientationEventListener` in your app?
- Do you have any logic in `onConfigurationChanged` that sets requested orientation?

**UPDATE after additional info was added:**

OK, now it makes sense.

Look, in order to achieve the behaviour you want, like in Youtube, most probably you will need to involve another component in the game, it's called: [OrientationEventListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener).

**This listener allows you to listen to changes in orientation directly from the Sensor.**

It does not matter if the Activity is locked in a specific orientation or not.

However, it's a bit more complex, this listener communicates the current orientation of device in degrees, from 0 to 359, you will have to figure out what range of degrees matches a landscape or portrait orientation.

The main idea is following:

- The minimize/maximize button will lock the activity in a specific orientation, just as you do it right now.
- Your implementation of `OrientationEventListener` will listen in background to the device orientation. When device orientation will match activity orientation, meaning the device is in landscape and the activity is also in landscape (or the other way around), you reset the activity orientation back to `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR`. From this point on your Activity will not be locked in a specific orientation, but start following the sensor again.
- Remove `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);` from `onConfigurationChanged()` as now this step is handled as described above.

For beginning start looking into `OrientationEventListener`. There are examples on SO how to use it.

Comment: Yes, I apologize for not adding this line, I call (updated to question) additionally to `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);` because you can't use the two ways orientation I'm looking for as after calling the `setRequestedOrientation(...` from the listener it blocks the sensor listener and forces the changes, so I'm trying to unlock it again, and that leads to these two calls.

Comment: I updated my answer depending on the new info provided.

Comment: Hi @AndyRes thanks for your answer. Is there a code sample for the updated part?

Comment: I mean is there a proper code sample for the updated part? Because the examples which implements OrientationEventListener just calculating x-y axis changes but it gives a faulty behaviour when z axis change